# Измение параметра сss с помощью команд.

Tags: jquery, html, css, javascript

Здравствуйте.

Делаю [сайт](http://trutee.ru/test5/).
И я хочу чтобы у меня сворачивалась шапка по нажатию на кнопку. Сворачиваться - сворачивается, но мне нужно также изменять картинку и позицию. Но это не происходит.

Как это исправить? Возможно дело в этом:

```
 onclick="if (document.getElementById('spoiler').style.display != '') {getElementById('spoiler').style.display = '';document.getElementById('bottonHead').style.background = 'url(open.png)';document.getelementsbyclassname('body').style.bottom = '0px';}else {document.getElementById('spoiler').style.display = 'none';document.getElementById('bottonHead').style.background = 'url(close.png)';document.getElementsByClassName('body').style.bottom = '46px';}"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Рекомендую завернуть код в функцию, будет приятнее и понятнее, а то писать прямо в онклике столько кода это перебор...
- Рекомендую использовать jquery. Код будет несколько компактнее. Сравните:

`document.getElementsByClassName('body')` и `$('.body')`

- Используйте `$('.body').show()` и `$('.body').hide()`

Это просто рекомендация, как проще.

Comment: Спасибо.
Что не кто не знает в чем проблема?

Comment: были подобные вопросы уже заданы. например, я помню задавался вопрос при нажатии на картинку, блок свернуть и заменить картинку. воспользуйтесь поиском. 

Ну а от себя подсказка можно создать два класса - одни для разворачивания, другой - для сворачивания. в этих классах указать позицию и фоновое изображение. при сворачивании/разворачивании добавлять/удалять эти классы.

Comment: Ошибку нашел. Она заключалась в том что у меня не было элемента с ID bottonHead, а был класс.